# Using Bluetooth to setup Wifi (Samsung) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, samsung, us20140308898

This application from Samsung seeks to patent a method for using one type of wireless connection, such as Bluetooth, to setup a second wireless connection such as Wi-Fi Direct.  10 minutes of your time can help narrow this US patent application before it becomes a patent.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 2013-Apr-16** that describes:

> - using one wireless protocol to setup a second wireless connection
> - using Bluetooth to setup a Wi-Fi Direct connection

If you've ever seen anything like this before, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question — one piece of prior art per answer. We welcome multiple answers from a single individual.

**Title**: Communication control method and electronic device implementing the same

**Summary**: A method for communicating with an electronic device. The method includes  establishing a communication channel between two devices and sending data through that channel in order to establish a second communication channel. This could include, for example, using Bluetooth to setup a Wi-Fi direct connection for transmitting image data from a smartphone to a tv.

- **Publication Number**: [US20140308898](http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PG01&s1=20140308898&OS=20140308898&RS=20140308898) (**NOTE**: Not available on Google Patent as of 2015-Jan-28)
- **App Number**: 14/254,860
- **Assignee**: Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 2013-Apr-16
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO**: Open through ~2015-Apr-16.

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A communication control method comprising:
>
> 1. establishing, at a source device, a preliminary channel via a first communications module;
> 2. communicating data for establishing a communication channel through the preliminary channel, the communication channel being established via a second communication module; and
> 3. establishing the communication channel via the second communication channel.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 2013-Apr-16.

What is good prior art? Please see the [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).

Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request) on other questionable US Patent Applications.

Prior art cited by applicants:
KR 10-2008-0071379
KR 10-2013-009088

Answer (score 1):

NFC can be used to pair bluetooth devices. The following paper was published in 2011:

["Bluetooth Secure Simple Pairing Using NFC"](http://members.nfc-forum.org/resources/AppDocs/NFCForum_AD_BTSSP_1_0.pdf)

Comment: Bluetooth also have a ['Simple Pairing' whitepaper](https://web.archive.org/web/20061018032605/http://www.bluetooth.com/NR/rdonlyres/0A0B3F36-D15F-4470-85A6-F2CCFA26F70F/0/SimplePairing_WP_V10r00.pdf) from 2006. Relevant section is 3.3 "Out Of Band". From the paper: "The information exchanged includes discovery information (such as
the Bluetooth Device Address) as well as cryptographic information. One of the devices will use the received Bluetooth
Device Address to establish a connection with the other device."

Answer (score 0):

WAP push maybe? It would send some initial message via SMS for example and request the phone to set up an IP channel.

Answer (score 0):

"Alternate MAC/PHY"

http://www.macworld.com/article/1140234/bluetooth.html "How Bluetooth got as fast as Wi-Fi"

http://www.gizmag.com/bluetooth-3-sig/11515/

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of setting up an Apple TV's WiFi settings by placing an iPhone on it which communicates via blue tooth.

Earliest mention I'm finding off-hand is September 2013, but surely there is an earlier mention somewhere? Granted it isn't for connecting the two devices together but rather to setup the Apple TV's own independent connection.

http://www.cnet.com/news/set-up-your-apple-tv-just-by-touching-it-with-your-ios-7-device/

Answer (score 0):

The KEYWORD is "HotSpot" regardless of is you use Bluetooth or any other way to connect the wireless hotspot being offered.

http://web.archive.org/web/20040212105815/http://sunnygrenada.com/index.html

Not filed as patent but prior art.

Samsung is a patent troll playing dumb.